# MYSQL query will remove characters from a string

Tags: mysql, sql, character

I would like to implement a query in MYSQL that will remove the characters before the space

For example :

> UA 016

i want to remove 'UA ' with the space , and only keep

> 016

here is the query statements:

```
update field_data_field_id set field_id_value = '.... what i need here';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE field_data_field_id 
SET field_id_value=SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                     SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_id_value,' ',2),' ',-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
 CREATE FUNCTION IsNumeric (val varchar(255)) RETURNS tinyint 
 RETURN val REGEXP '^(-|\\+){0,1}([0-9]+\\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)$';

 CREATE FUNCTION NumericOnly (val VARCHAR(255)) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
 BEGIN
 DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 0;
 IF ISNULL(val) THEN RETURN NULL; END IF;

 IF LENGTH(val) = 0 THEN RETURN ""; END IF;

 SET idx = LENGTH(val);
 WHILE idx > 0 DO
 IF IsNumeric(SUBSTRING(val,idx,1)) = 0 THEN
 SET val = REPLACE(val,SUBSTRING(val,idx,1),"");
 SET idx = LENGTH(val)+1;
 END IF;
 SET idx = idx - 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN val;
  END;
```

---

Use it by calling the NumericOnly function like this:

```
select NumericOnly('1&2') as result;
```

Returns: "12"

```
select NumericOnly('abc987') as result;
```

Returns: "987"

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET column=REPLACE(column,SUBSTRING_INDEX(column,' ',1),'');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34a67/1)

Assuming all values have a space.

Comment: IF he has  characters AFTER the first space it will break,yes.But he didnt say that.